# How to generate new number when you generate new record?

Tags: c#

I have a task. Task where I need to generate number when load new loading list. I did a formular in which is field called "LoadingListNumber". What I need is generate this number in format: 04/0001/19 (Month/LoadingListNumber/Year). The number 0001 is loaded when its new record. So if you have new record it will be 0001, another record 0002,0010 etc. I know how to generate the month and year, but not this number :/

I have already generated month in this sentence and year.

```
NumberOfLoadingList = string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString("YY"));
```

I really need a tip or advice, how to generate the number. Thank you.

Comment: Create a `rand` variable between 1 and whatever and add it to the string or however you want to build it

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to accomplish here

Comment: you need 1. select max number from existing records with given year and month 2. increment it 3. use it ... this operations should be atomic (lock/db transaction)

Comment: With your code (calling DateTime.Now twice)You have a very small chance of getting the month in one year and the year in another.

Comment: does the sequence ever reset? does it cycle when it reaches 9999? how do you plan on storing/retrieving the last sequence?

Comment: ... or if you have only problem with formating then you may use [`string.Format("{0:MM}/{1:0000}/{0:yy}", ...);`](https://ideone.com/hSXYVb) (and find some basic C# course as using string.Format like this `string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString("YY"))` makes no sens - it is the same as `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString("YY")`)

Comment: ALFA already answered that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it a bit different than ALFA has suggested..

This is a full example of a console application, but I'm sure you can see what I'm trying to do here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    // This is a list of all your previous numbers
    // this could come from database or calculated somewhere in your application
    private static List<int> numbersList = new List<int>(); 

    public static void Main()
    {
        string NumberOfLoadingList; 

        for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            NumberOfLoadingList = string.Format("{0}/{1:0000}/{2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM"), GenerateNewNumber(), DateTime.Now.ToString("yy"));
            Console.WriteLine(NumberOfLoadingList);
        }
    }

    private static int GenerateNewNumber()
    {
        int number = 0;

        while(true) 
        {
            // Make sure the number is unique
            if (!numbersList.Contains(++number)) 
            {
                numbersList.Add(number);
                return number;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

You can try it out here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mtT1MS

Output of this application is:

```
04/0001/19
04/0002/19
04/0003/19
04/0004/19
04/0005/19
04/0006/19
04/0007/19
04/0008/19
04/0009/19
04/0010/19
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`padding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding) and a simple `loop` where you generates records:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'));
}
```

### Output

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
0010
0011
0012
0013
0014
0015
0016
[...]
0099
```

Comment: I think he's looking for how to generate the number, not format it

Comment: Yeah it may be, it's quite unclear actually. I'll leave this here in case it could help him and I'll wait for further information.

Comment: Another way: `for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) Console.WriteLine($"{i:0000}");` (or `i.ToString("0000")`)

Comment: Thank you, that is pretty much I need :]